# Getting two elements from a map which their sum equals to a desired number

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to find a way to get the first 2 elements from a map which their value combined gives me a desired sum.
I was thinking of a solution which combined 2 maps where the key of the second map is the reminder of the target number minus the value of the entry of the first map.
I am lost and not sure what I am missing.
What am I missing here?

Comment: what does it mean "the first 2 elements" ? did you mean "any 2 elements"? also, method `getTwoItemsWhichSumTo100()` is named incorrectly since it receives target which can be different than 100...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest introducing a new Map `remainderToItem`, looping through all relevant items and adding their reminder to the Map as key and item key as the value

then iterate the `relevantItems` Map again to find the price is matching with some other reminder
Also check `remainderToItem.get(entry.getValue()).equals(entry.getKey()))` *(in case the value is 50 reminder is also 50)*, this prevents adding same item again to `itemsThatCanBeBought`

```
private static List<String> getTwoItemsWhichSumTo100(Map<String, Integer> items, int target) {

    Map<String, Integer> relevantItems = getRelevantItems(items, target);
    Map<Integer, String> remainderToItem = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> itemsThatCanBeBought = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : relevantItems.entrySet()) {
        int remainder = target - entry.getValue();
        remainderToItem.put(remainder, entry.getKey());
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : relevantItems.entrySet()) {

        if (remainderToItem.containsKey(entry.getValue()) && !remainderToItem.get(entry.getValue()).equals(entry.getKey())) {
            itemsThatCanBeBought.add(entry.getKey());
            itemsThatCanBeBought.add(remainderToItem.get(entry.getValue()));
            return itemsThatCanBeBought;
        }
    }
    return itemsThatCanBeBought;
}

private static Map<String, Integer> getRelevantItems(Map<String, Integer> items, int target) {
    Map<String, Integer> relevantItems = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : items.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() < target) relevantItems.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return relevantItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem you're facing is that the int is the value , not the key.
so `pairOfItems.containsKey(remainder)` should not compile.
luckily for you, Map also has `containsValue()` method. as long as there is no requirement for minimum performance, that should solve your problem.
...and you don't need a 2nd map. you can just ask `items.containsValue(reminder)`